# Determine the dimension of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, with $a\neq b$ and let $V \subset P_n(\mathbb{R})$  be the linear subspace of all polynomials that vanish at $a$ and $b$, i.e. $V= \{f\in P_n(\mathbb{R}) \mid f(a)=f(b)=0\}$

$a$)  Define the nullspace $N(T)$, where $T:P_n(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R^2}$ is some arbitrary linear transformation.

My answer, $N(T) = \{x\in P_n(\mathbb{R}) : T(x) = 0\}$

$b)$  Determine the dimension of $V$.

To answer this I have begun to use the rank-nullity/dimension theorem

Nullity($T$) + Rank($T$) = Dim($V$)

in this case would Nullity($T$) $=2$

Really not sure where to go from here or if I'm correct so far, thanks in advance

Comment: The number $n$ doesn't appear in the definition of $P_n(\mathbb{R})$? Are you sure about that?

Comment: $N(T) = \{v \in V : T(v) = 0\}$ just assumed i had to change it for this certain question? @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: I don't see how this is supposed to be an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose (cf.José Carlos comment) that by $P_n(\mathbb{R})$ You mean the polynomials of  degree at most $n$, then define
$$T:P_n(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}²,f\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}f(a)\\f(b)\end{pmatrix}$$
It is easy to check that $T$ is linear and obviously $N(T)=V$.
Then because $R(T)=\mathbb{R}²$ (where $R(T)$ is the range of $T$):
$$\underbrace{\dim(V)}_{\dim(N(T))}+\underbrace{\dim (R(T))}_{=2}=\dim(P_n(\mathbb{R}))=n+1$$
and thus $\dim(V)=n-1$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\dim P_n(\mathbb{R}) = n+1$.

Notice that the subspace $W = \{f \in P_n(\mathbb{R}) : f(a) = 0\}$ has dimension $n$.
Indeed, check that $\{(x-a)^k : 1 \le k \le n\} \subseteq W$ is linearly independent so $\dim W \ge n-1$, and $W \ne P_n(\mathbb{R})$ so $\dim W < n+1$. Hence $\dim W = n$.

Now $V$ is a subspace of $W$ and check that $\{(x-a)^k(x-b) : 1 \le k \le n-1\} \subseteq V$ is linearly independent so $\dim V \ge n-1$. On the other hand, $V \ne W$ so $\dim V < \dim W = n$. Therefore $\dim V = n-1$.